# Highlight During Hover in Plotly - not working?

Tags: r, shiny, hover, plotly, highlight

Context: I am trying to plot a line graph with multiple time series at once. The groups are described by ~Country. Only those countries that are selected by the user (input$Country) in a shiny app are displayed in the graph. The user also defines the x and y variables.

Problem: I would like to use the highlight feature to highlight each time series when there is a hover event. The graph seems to recognize the highlight syntax, because the color selecting widget specified by Dynamic=TRUE is there. The lines themselves do not get highlighted during the mouseover, however.

Can anyone see where the error is and what would allow the highlight function to work during hover?

```
server <- function(input, output, ...) {

highlight_key(data, key=~Country)

    output$p <- renderPlotly({
      (plot_ly(data, x = ~get(input$xvar), y = ~get(input$yvar), mode='lines', color= ~Country) %>%
      filter(Country %in% input$Country) %>%
      add_lines(line=list(width=3)) %>% 
      layout(yaxis = list(type = input$yscale, title = input$yvar))%>% 
      layout(xaxis = list(title = "Title of X"))%>% 
      config(displayModeBar = FALSE, scrollZoom=TRUE)%>%
      filter(Country %in% input$Country)%>%
      highlight(on='plotly_hover',off='plotly_doubleclick',dynamic=TRUE))  

  })
}
```

Comment: Hi, please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will be much easier to help you with that

Comment: Don't you have to do `dat <- highlight_key(data, key=~Country)` and then `plot_ly(dat, ......)` ?

Comment: Yes! Using Stéphane's code worked. Thank you!